# Modify tab delimited txt file

Tags: awk, sed

I want to modify tab delimited txt file using linux commands sed/awk/or any other method

This is an example of tab delimited txt file which I want to modify for R boxplot input:

----start of input format---------

```
chr8    38277027    38277127    Ex8_inner
    25425   8   100 0.0800000
chr8    38277027    38277127    Ex8_inner
    25426   4   100 0.0400000
chr9    38277027    38277127    Ex9_inner
    25427   9   100 0.0900000
chr9    38277027    38277127    Ex9_inner
    25428   1   100 0.0100000
chr10   38277027    38277127    Ex10_inner
    30935   1   100 0.0100000
chr10   38277027    38277127    Ex10_inner
    31584   1   100 0.0100000
all 687 1   1000    0.0010000
all 694 1   1000    0.0010000
all 695 1   1000    0.0010000
all 697 1   1000    0.0010000
all 699 6   1000    0.0060000
all 700 2   1000    0.0020000
all 723 7   1000    0.0070000
all 740 8   1000    0.0080000
all 742 1   1000    0.0010000
all 761 5   1000    0.0050000
all 814 2   1000    0.0020000
all 821 48  1000    0.0480000
```

------end of input file format------

I want it to be modified so that 4th column of odd rows becomes 1st column and 2nd column of the even rows (1st column is blank) becomes 2nd column. Rows starting with "all" gets deleted.

This is how output file should look:

-----start of the output file----

```
Ex8_inner 25425
Ex8_inner 25426
Ex9_inner 25427
Ex9_inner 25428
Ex10_inner 30935
Ex10_inner 31584
```

-----end of the output file----

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be clear in your question and wrap up your code in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I have no clue how to do it. I am new to all this.

Comment: Click on EDIT button in your post and then you will see a BUTTON like {} select your sample  Input_file and click on {} to wrap that up in CODE TAGS and similarly do for all examples(only for sample data not for your language please). you could use backticks too for keeping data in code tags too.

Comment: i hope this is good enough

Comment: Sure, check my solution now too on same and let us know in case of any queries too, happy learning cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As OP has changed Input_file sample a bit so adding code too it.

```
awk --re-interval 'match($0,/Exon[0-9]{1,}/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);getline;sub(/^ +/,"",$1);print val,$1}'   Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** My `awk` is old version to I added `--re-interval` to it you need not to add it in case you have recent version of it too.

---

With single `awk` following may help you on same too.

```
awk '/Ex[0-9]+_inner/{val=$NF;getline;sub(/^ +/,"",$1);print val,$1}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here for same.

```
awk '
/Ex[0-9]+_inner/{    ##Checking condition here if a line contains string Ex then digits _inner if yes then do following actions.
   val=$NF;          ##Creating variable named val whose value is $NF(last field of current line).
   getline;          ##using getline which is out of the box keyword of awk to take the cursor to the next line from current line.
   sub(/^ +/,"",$1); ##Using sub utility of awk to substitute initial space of first field with NULL.
   print val,$1      ##Printing variable named val and first field value here.
}
' Input_file         ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi. It works. However when I try to run it on file with more number of rows I am getting a blank output.

Comment: @RonicK, kindly do let me know examples for it, could look into it then.

Comment: hi Ravi. Added one more example. The number of rows will vary with each file. So i want a common command which will work for all the files.

Comment: @RonicK, please check my EDIT solution now too(seems your sample Input_file is different from previous shown) this should work for the added samples ones too, let me know how it goes from here.

Comment: @RonicK, np sir, keep learning and keep posting sharing in SO, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '/^all/{next} 
      !/^chr/{printf "%s\n", $1; next} 
             {printf "%s ", $NF}' file

Ex8_inner 25425
Ex8_inner 25426
Ex9_inner 25427
Ex9_inner 25428
Ex10_inner 30935
Ex10_inner 31584
```

or perhaps

```
$ awk '!/^all/{if(/^chr/) printf "%s", $NF OFS; else print $1}' file
```

Comment: Thanks Karakfa, It worked. Samething again - if I want to run it on similar file with more rows output is not correct.

Comment: the code is tailored for the sample input, if your actual format is different it may not work.